# Encrypt QDataStream with AES

Tags: c++, qt, crypto++

im writing a Qt application on linux (Qt 4.8.1) which writes data byte by byte to a QDataStream object. The data stream goes into a file.
Now i need to encrypt this data with AES-256.
I choose crypto++ lib for this purpose but im struggling with the implementation.

Does anybody know if it is possible at all to encrypt a QDataStream with the given filter classes of crypto++ lib?

greetz 
maggie

Answer (score 2):

Might be a interesting to reimplement QIODevice, or maybe better QFile... In particular I would reimplement:

```
virtual qint64 readData(char* data, qint64 maxSize) = 0;
virtual qint64 readLineData(char* data, qint64 maxSize);
virtual qint64 writeData(const char* data, qint64 maxSize) = 0;
```

This way you should be able to use QDataStream transparently.

Comment: I like this idea - sounds almost too easy.  Are those the only QFile methods used by QDataStream?